# Manual Back Press From FragmentA to Homefragment Did Not Work Android Studio,

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I Have one Fragment called LatestFragment Code:

```
public class LatestFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<ItemLatest> mListItem;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LatestAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayout lyt_not_found;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);


        mListItem = new ArrayList<>();

        lyt_not_found = rootView.findViewById(R.id.lyt_not_found);
        progressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.vertical_courses_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1));
        recyclerView.setFocusable(false);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        JsonObject jsObj = (JsonObject) new Gson().toJsonTree(new API());
        jsObj.addProperty("method_name", "get_latest");
        if (JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(requireActivity())) {
            new getLatest(API.toBase64(jsObj.toString())).execute(Constant.API_URL);
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private class getLatest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String base64;

        private getLatest(String base64) {
            this.base64 = base64;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showProgress(true);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             return JsonUtils.getJSONString(params[0], base64);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            showProgress(false);
            if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
                lyt_not_found.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                try {
                    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(Constant.ARRAY_NAME);
                    JSONObject objJson;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        if(objJson.has("status")){
                            lyt_not_found.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else {
                        ItemLatest objItem = new ItemLatest();
                        objItem.setRecipeId(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_ID));
                        objItem.setRecipeName(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_NAME));
                        objItem.setRecipeType(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_TYPE));
                        objItem.setRecipePlayId(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_VIDEO_PLAY));
                        objItem.setRecipeImageSmall(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_IMAGE_SMALL));
                        objItem.setRecipeImageBig(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_IMAGE_BIG));
                        objItem.setRecipeViews(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_VIEW));
                        objItem.setRecipeTime(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_TIME));
                        objItem.setRecipeCategoryName(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_CAT_NAME));
                        objItem.setRecipeTotalRate(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_TOTAL_RATE));
                        objItem.setRecipeAvgRate(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_AVR_RATE));
                        objItem.setRecipeDirection(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_DIRE));
                        objItem.setRecipeIngredient(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_INGREDIENT));

                        mListItem.add(objItem);

                    }}
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                displayData();

            }

        }
    }


    private void displayData() {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            adapter = new LatestAdapter(getActivity(), mListItem);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            if (adapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                lyt_not_found.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                lyt_not_found.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }
    }

    private void showProgress(boolean show) {
        if (show) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lyt_not_found.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);



        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search)
                .getActionView();

        final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                    searchView.setQuery("", false);
                }
            }
        });



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
             //   finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

}
```

And HomeFragment Code:

```
package com.example.fragment;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mCatView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), mCatView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {

                if (Constant.SAVE_ADS_FULL_ON_OFF.equals("true")) {

                    Constant.AD_COUNT++;
                    if (Constant.AD_COUNT == Integer.parseInt(Constant.SAVE_ADS_CLICK)) {
                        Constant.AD_COUNT = 0;
                        final InterstitialAd mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(requireActivity());
                        mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(Constant.SAVE_ADS_FULL_ID);
                        AdRequest adRequest;
                        if (JsonUtils.personalization_ad) {
                            adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                    .build();
                        } else {
                            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                            extras.putString("npa", "1");
                            adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                    .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
                                    .build();
                        }
                        mInterstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
                        mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdLoaded() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                super.onAdLoaded();
                                if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                                    mInterstitial.show();
                                }
                            }

                            public void onAdClosed() {
                                String categoryName = mCatList.get(position).getCategoryName();
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("name", categoryName);
                                bundle.putString("Id", mCatList.get(position).getCategoryId());

                                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                                SubCategoryFragment subCategoryFragment = new SubCategoryFragment();
                                subCategoryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                assert fm != null;
                                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                                ft.hide(HomeFragment.this);
                                ft.add(R.id.fragment1, subCategoryFragment, categoryName);
                                ft.addToBackStack(categoryName);
                                ft.commit();
                                ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).setToolbarTitle(categoryName);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                                String categoryName = mCatList.get(position).getCategoryName();
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("name", categoryName);
                                bundle.putString("Id", mCatList.get(position).getCategoryId());

                                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                                SubCategoryFragment subCategoryFragment = new SubCategoryFragment();
                                subCategoryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                assert fm != null;
                                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                                ft.hide(HomeFragment.this);
                                ft.add(R.id.fragment1, subCategoryFragment, categoryName);
                                ft.addToBackStack(categoryName);
                                ft.commit();
                                ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).setToolbarTitle(categoryName);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        String categoryName = mCatList.get(position).getCategoryName();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("name", categoryName);
                        bundle.putString("Id", mCatList.get(position).getCategoryId());

                        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        SubCategoryFragment subCategoryFragment = new SubCategoryFragment();
                        subCategoryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        assert fm != null;
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                        ft.hide(HomeFragment.this);
                        ft.add(R.id.fragment1, subCategoryFragment, categoryName);
                        ft.addToBackStack(categoryName);
                        ft.commit();
                        ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).setToolbarTitle(categoryName);
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        btnCat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).highLightNavigation(2);
                String categoryName = getString(R.string.home_category);
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                CategoryFragment f1 = new CategoryFragment();
                assert fm != null;
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, f1, categoryName);
                ft.commit();
                ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).setToolbarTitle(categoryName);
            }
        });

        btnLatest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).highLightNavigation(1);
                String categoryName = getString(R.string.home_latest);
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                LatestFragment f1 = new LatestFragment();
                assert fm != null;
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, f1, categoryName);
                ft.commit();
                ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).setToolbarTitle(categoryName);
            }
        });

        btnMost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).highLightNavigation(3);
                String categoryName = getString(R.string.menu_most);
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                MostViewFragment f1 = new MostViewFragment();
                assert fm != null;
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, f1, categoryName);
                ft.commit();
                ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).setToolbarTitle(categoryName);
            }
        });

        edt_search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    //do something
                    String st_search = edt_search.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("search", st_search);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    edt_search.getText().clear();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private class Home extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String base64;

        private Home(String base64) {
            this.base64 = base64;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mScrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return JsonUtils.getJSONString(params[0], base64);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
                showToast(getString(R.string.no_data));
            } else {

                try {
                    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONObject jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONObject(Constant.ARRAY_NAME);
                    JSONArray jsonSlider = jsonArray.getJSONArray(Constant.HOME_FEATURED_ARRAY);
                    JSONObject objJsonSlider;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonSlider.length(); i++) {
                        objJsonSlider = jsonSlider.getJSONObject(i);

                        ItemLatest objItem = new ItemLatest();
                        objItem.setRecipeId(objJsonSlider.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_ID));
                        objItem.setRecipeType(objJsonSlider.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_TYPE));
                        objItem.setRecipeCategoryName(objJsonSlider.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_CAT_NAME));
                        objItem.setRecipeName(objJsonSlider.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_NAME));
                        objItem.setRecipeImageBig(objJsonSlider.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_IMAGE_BIG));
                        objItem.setRecipeImageSmall(objJsonSlider.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_IMAGE_SMALL));
                        objItem.setRecipePlayId(objJsonSlider.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_VIDEO_PLAY));
                        mSliderList.add(objItem);
                    }
                    JSONArray jsonLatest = jsonArray.getJSONArray(Constant.HOME_LATEST_CAT);
                    JSONObject objJsonCat;
                    for (int k = 0; k < jsonLatest.length(); k++) {
                        objJsonCat = jsonLatest.getJSONObject(k);
                        ItemCategory objItem = new ItemCategory();
                        objItem.setCategoryId(objJsonCat.getString(Constant.CATEGORY_ID));
                        objItem.setCategoryName(objJsonCat.getString(Constant.CATEGORY_NAME));
                        objItem.setCategoryImageBig(objJsonCat.getString(Constant.CATEGORY_IMAGE_BIG));
                        objItem.setCategoryImageSmall(objJsonCat.getString(Constant.CATEGORY_IMAGE_SMALL));
                        mCatList.add(objItem);
                    }

                    JSONArray jsonPopular = jsonArray.getJSONArray(Constant.HOME_LATEST_ARRAY);
                    JSONObject objJson;
                    for (int l = 0; l < jsonPopular.length(); l++) {
                        objJson = jsonPopular.getJSONObject(l);
                        ItemLatest objItem = new ItemLatest();
                        objItem.setRecipeId(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_ID));
                        objItem.setRecipeName(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_NAME));
                        objItem.setRecipeType(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_TYPE));
                        objItem.setRecipePlayId(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_VIDEO_PLAY));
                        objItem.setRecipeImageSmall(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_IMAGE_SMALL));
                        objItem.setRecipeImageBig(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_IMAGE_BIG));
                        objItem.setRecipeViews(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_VIEW));
                        objItem.setRecipeTime(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_TIME));
                        objItem.setRecipeAvgRate(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_AVR_RATE));
                        objItem.setRecipeTotalRate(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_TOTAL_RATE));
                        objItem.setRecipeCategoryName(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_CAT_NAME));
                        mLatestList.add(objItem);
                    }

                    JSONArray jsonPopularMost = jsonArray.getJSONArray(Constant.HOME_MOST_ARRAY);
                    JSONObject objJsonMost;
                    for (int l = 0; l < jsonPopularMost.length(); l++) {
                        objJsonMost = jsonPopularMost.getJSONObject(l);
                        ItemLatest objItem = new ItemLatest();
                        objItem.setRecipeId(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_ID));
                        objItem.setRecipeName(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_NAME));
                        objItem.setRecipeType(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_TYPE));
                        objItem.setRecipePlayId(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_VIDEO_PLAY));
                        objItem.setRecipeImageSmall(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_IMAGE_SMALL));
                        objItem.setRecipeImageBig(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_IMAGE_BIG));
                        objItem.setRecipeViews(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_VIEW));
                        objItem.setRecipeTime(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_TIME));
                        objItem.setRecipeAvgRate(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_AVR_RATE));
                        objItem.setRecipeTotalRate(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_TOTAL_RATE));
                        objItem.setRecipeCategoryName(objJsonMost.getString(Constant.LATEST_RECIPE_CAT_NAME));
                        mMostList.add(objItem);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                setResult();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setResult() {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            mLatestAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(), mLatestList);
            mLatestView.setAdapter(mLatestAdapter);

            homeMostAdapter = new HomeMostAdapter(getActivity(), mMostList);
            mMostView.setAdapter(homeMostAdapter);

            homeCategoryAdapter = new HomeCategoryAdapter(getActivity(), mCatList);
            mCatView.setAdapter(homeCategoryAdapter);

            if (!mSliderList.isEmpty()) {
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                if (mSliderList.size() >= 3) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private class CustomViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        private CustomViewPagerAdapter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mSliderList.size();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_slider_item, container, false);
            assert imageLayout != null;
            ImageView image = imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            TextView text = imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
            TextView text_cat = imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_cat_title);
            LinearLayout lytParent = imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

            text.setText(mSliderList.get(position).getRecipeName());
            text_cat.setText(mSliderList.get(position).getRecipeCategoryName());

            Picasso.get().load(mSliderList.get(position).getRecipeImageBig()).into(image);
            imageLayout.setTag(EnchantedViewPager.ENCHANTED_VIEWPAGER_POSITION + position);
            lytParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PopUpAds.ShowInterstitialAds(getActivity(), mSliderList.get(position).getRecipeId());
                }
            });
            container.addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            (container).removeView((View) object);
        }
    }

    public void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile, menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
             //   finish();
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_profile:
                if (MyApp.getIsLogin()) {
                    Intent intent_edit = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileEditActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent_edit);
                } else {
                    final PrettyDialog dialog = new PrettyDialog(requireActivity());
                    dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_warning))
                            .setTitleColor(R.color.dialog_text)
                            .setMessage(getString(R.string.login_require))
                            .setMessageColor(R.color.dialog_text)
                            .setAnimationEnabled(false)
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.pdlg_icon_close, R.color.dialog_color, new PrettyDialogCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick() {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                            .addButton(getString(R.string.dialog_ok), R.color.dialog_white_text, R.color.dialog_color, new PrettyDialogCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick() {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Intent intent_login = new Intent(getActivity(), SignInActivity.class);
                                    intent_login.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent_login);
                                }
                            })
                            .addButton(getString(R.string.dialog_no), R.color.dialog_white_text, R.color.dialog_color, new PrettyDialogCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick() {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    dialog.show();
                }
                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

When It load LatestFragment and I press back in android device the app Exit,
how to backpress from LatestFragment to HomeFragment
Thanks

Is there a way in which we can implement onBackPressed() in Android Fragment similar to the way in which we implement in Android Activity?

As the Fragment lifecycle do not have onBackPressed(). Is there any other alternative method to over ride onBackPressed() in Android 3.5 fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease change in HomeFragment
 `ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, f1, categoryName);` to

```
ft.add(R.id.fragment1, f1, categoryName);
```

It adds `LatestFragment` in stack so when you will press back button from `LatestFragment` it shows `HomeFragment` because `HomeFragment` is still in stack

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the answer it work perfectly I add this and it work:ft.hide(HomeFragment.this);
                ft.add(R.id.fragment1, f1, categoryName);
                ft.addToBackStack(categoryName); Thanks @Jaimil Patel